# can't import the test helper addon in ember-cli-mirage

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage, ember-cli-addons

Facing the same issue - https://github.com/miragejs/ember-cli-mirage/issues/1445

Uncaught Error: Could not find module `project-name/tests/helpers/push-mirage-into-store` imported from `project-name/mirage/factories/addon`

Initially got this error and tried **@makepanic** instructions

After that

Uncaught Error: Could not find module `@ember/test-helpers` imported from `project-name/mirage/helpers/push-mirage-into-store`

can you pls help here to resolve this.

Comment: Can you provide some more context? What does `push-mirage-into-store.js` look like? Are you seeing this issue when running tests or running in development?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are running into the error, which is described [in this comment by makepanic in the GitHub issue you linked](https://github.com/miragejs/ember-cli-mirage/issues/1445#issuecomment-466107990):

> When running the app directly, the browser opens index.html which
> isn't loading tests.js. This file contains everything related to
> tests.
>
> If you open tests/index.html, that will also load tests.js and add any
> modules under tests/* to the loader registry.
>
> This means without the tests file loaded, you can't import anything
> from tests/*.

You are affected by that issue if you face it when running `ember serve`.

The comment also includes a possible solution:

> With you moving the helpers to /mirage, they gets registered in both index.html and tests/index.html.

An alternative would be to disable mirage in all enrironments except for `test`. But that is only a feasible solution if you use mirage only for testing but not for development.